# Is there any way to pass a DOM element as a prop in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vuejs3, vue-props

I'm super new to Vue. While I don't normally do this, I think something like this would be possible in React + JSX (untested):

```
render() {
  const el = <p>Blah <a href="https://example.com">bloop</a> bleh</p>
  return (
    <div>
      <CustomReactComponent someProp={el}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Where `CustomReactComponent` would be able to render the element out of `this.props.someProp`.

Can I achieve this in Vue?

---

**For the curious,** my use case is similar to my very untested React example above. I would like some, but not all parent components of a common tiny component to pass in some text to display somewhere. Except I'd like to include links wherever I please, so I need `<a>` tags in there. I figured I could make that work by passing a whole `<p>` or `<span>` element as a prop.

**Alternate solutions welcome!**

Comment: This is what slots are for.

Comment: Wow thanks for that pointer. Exactly what I needed! I guess this was a dumb question since I didn't read through the entire tutorial before starting a project, but I'll leave it up for people looking up this behavior with similar keywords as me. Feel free to convert your comment to an answer that I can accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Estus said in their comment, this is what the [slots feature](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-slots.html) is for.